# Difference between char a[]="string"; char *p="string";

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

What is the difference between `char a[]="string";` and `char *p="string";`?

Comment: Could you make this question shorter?

Comment: @liori: char a[]=“s”; != char *p=“s”; ?  :)

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char *s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

Answer (score 29):

The first one is array the other is pointer.

The array declaration "`char a[6];`" requests that space for six characters be set aside, to be known by the name "`a.`"  That is, there is a location named "`a`" at which six characters can sit. The pointer declaration "`char *p;`" on the other hand, requests a place which holds a pointer.  The pointer is to be known by the name "`p,`" and can point to any char (or contiguous array of chars) anywhere.

The statements

```
char a[] = "hello";
char *p = "world";
```

would result in data structures which could be represented like this:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
a: | h | e | l | l | o |\0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
p: |  *======> | w | o | r | l | d |\0 |
   +-----+     +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

It is important to realize that a reference like x[3] generates different code depending on whether x is an array or a pointer. Given the declarations above, when the compiler sees the expression a[3], it emits code to start at the location "a," move three past it, and fetch the character there.  When it sees the expression p[3], it emits code to start at the location "p," fetch the pointer value there, add three to the pointer, and finally fetch the character pointed to.  In the example above, both a[3] and p[3] happen to be the character 'l', but the compiler gets there differently.

You can use search there are tons of explanations on the subject in th internet.

Comment: where is the memory allocated in the first case and where in the second case? stack? heap? when you decide to point p to somethng else does that mean that "wrold" will be deallocated?

Comment: @Ram Bhat: in the first case, it depends on where that definition is placed; if it's in a function, probably on the stack, if it is in a struct, it depends from where the whole struct is allocated; if it's outside any function, in the global vars segment. The same holds for the pointer p; the "world" string to which p points, instead, *usually* is in a particular section of the executable which is mapped in memory at loading, which is used as string table.

Answer (score 10):

`char a[]="string";` //`a` is an array of characters.

`char *p="string";`// `p` is a string literal having static allocation. Any attempt to modify contents of `p` leads to Undefined Behavior since string literals are stored in read-only section of memory.

Answer (score 3):

No difference. Unless you want to actually write to the array, in which case the whole world will explode if you try to use the second form. See [here](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Answer (score 2):

First declaration declares an array, while second - a pointer.

If you're interested in difference in some particular aspect, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that sizeof(a)-1 will be replaced with the length of the string at compile time.  With p you need to use strlen(p) to get the length at runtime.  Also some compilers don't like char *p="string", they want const char *p="string" in which case the memory for "string" is read-only but the memory for a is not.  Even if the compiler does not require the const declaration it's bad practice to modify the string pointed to by p (ie *p='a').  The pointer p can be changed to point to something else.  With the array a, a new value has to be copied into the array (if it fits).