# Difference between char[] and char*?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C - Difference between “char var[]” and “char *var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880573/c-difference-between-char-var-and-char-var)
>   [Difference between char a[]=“string”; char *p=“string”;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938895/difference-between-char-a-string-char-p-string)

would someone explain what exactly the difference between char[] and char* is?
for example difference between

```
char name[] = "earth";
```

and

```
char *name = "earth";
```

thanks

Comment: AFAIK there is none in your example.

Comment: @Constantinius There _is_ one: the first declares a new array that contains the characters of `"earth"`, while the second is a pointer that points to the `"earth"` literal. Modifying the former is legal, modifying the latter is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, try `name++` and you'll see the difference. Also `sizeof(name)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
char namea[] = "earth";
char *pname = "earth";
```

One is an array (the name `namea` refers to a *block* of characters).

The other is a pointer to a single character (the name `pname` refers to a pointer, which just happens to point to the first character of a block of characters).

Although the former will often decay into the latter, that's not always the case. Try doing a `sizeof` on them both to see what I mean.

The size of the array is, well, the size of the array (six characters, including the terminal null).

The size of the pointer is dependent on your pointer width (4 or 8, or whatever). The size of what `pname` *points to* is not the array, but the first character. It will therefore be 1.

You can also *move* pointers with things like `pname++` (unless they're declared constant, with something like `char *const pname = ...;` of course). You can't move an array name to point to it's second character (`namea++;`).

Comment: `char *name = "earth"` is deprecated in C++03.It **Must** be `const char *name = "earth"`. Also it is apt to add that modifying an String literal *in anyway* leads to an UB.

Answer (score 2):

```
(1) char name[] = "earth";
```

`name` is an character array having the contents as, `'e'`,`'a'`,`'r'`,`'t'`,`'h'`,`0`. The storage location of this characters depends on where `name[]` is declared (*typically* either stack or data segment).

```
(2) char *name = "earth";
```

`name` is a pointer to a const string. The storage location of `"earth"` is in **read-only** memory area.

In C++, this is deprecated and it should be `const char *name = "earth";`

Answer (score 1):

1. char `name[]= "earth";` creates a mutable array on the stack with the size of 6 with the value `earth\0`.
2. `char* name = "earth";` defines a pointer to a string constant with the value `earth\0`.

Answer (score 0):

`char[]` describes an array of char with a fixed number of elements.

`char*` describes a pointer to a char, typically followed in memory by a sequence of char's typically terminated by a null char `\0`

Answer (score 0):

With

```
char *name = "earth"
```

you must not modify the contents of name.

Hence

```
name[2] = 'A';
```

char* is terminated by a '\0' character while name[] has fixed size.

will cause a segfault.

> Initializing the variable takes a huge performance and space penalty
>   for the array. Only use the array method if you intend on changing the
>   string, it takes up space in the stack and adds some serious overhead
>   every time you enter the variable's scope. Use the pointer method
>   otherwise.