# my c code giving same output for every input of p?

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // your code goes here
    char *p;
    p = "hello";

    printf("%s",*&*&p);
    return 0;
}
```

It give same output for `p`, `*&p`, `*&*&p`. how is this possible?

Comment: What do you expect, instead?

Comment: how can value of p be hello. p store address.

Comment: can some explain me step by step working of this code?

Comment: `p` stores the address that the string `"hello"` starts at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` means give whatever is at this location in memory.
`&` gives the memory address of this object.

Therefore:
`p` is the address that the string `hello` starts at.
`*&p` means give me whatever is at the location of p (i.e. the address that `hello` starts at).
`*&*&p` means give me whatever is at the location that is at the location of p

So all of those just give you `p`.

Comment: but p cannot store value, it should be an address?

Comment: So the address that is stored in `p` is sent to `printf` and `printf` starts printing characters at that address until it sees a `\0`

Comment: when we give p =20, and  printf("%d",*&*&p); then it will not work right?

Comment: @NishantKumar Yes, it would be trying to read from memory address 20 which is probably invalid, so you'd get a seg fault.

Comment: @NishantKumar You should get a compiler error because you're assigning an `int` to a `char*`

Comment: ok then if  char p= "hello"; printf("%s",p); it prints error but  char *p;p="hello";

    printf("%s",p); it prints hello

Comment: @NishantKumar Correct, you cannot assign a string (which is an array of `char`s) to a single `char`.

Comment: ok last question does in char *p; p= "hello", p store address pf string hello

Comment: how its store adress of the string, bcz when give p = 20, it store it as address.

Comment: @NishantKumar It stores the address that the string starts at. Try `printf("%p", p)` to see the address, `printf("%c", *p)` for the first character, `printf("%c", *(p+1))` for the second character and so on.

Comment: In C, "`p` is the string" is not correct.  A string is a character array/sequence up to and including a null character.  A string is not a pointer.   `p` is type `char *` - a pointer.  `p` has a value of an address.  `p` has the value of the address of the first character of a string.

Comment: @chux You're correct, but sometimes it's easier to think about the pointer to a character array that is null terminated as a string even though that's not technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

p is the pointer pointing to string "hello". &p is address of p , So *&p will be the value at address of p which is again the pointer pointing to string "hello"

Comment: ok then if  char p= "hello"; printf("%s",p); it prints error but  char *p;p="hello";

    printf("%s",p); it prints hello

Comment: Because char p means p is a single character and not a string. char *p means that p is a pointer to a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2938924/4183255 for understanding.

Comment: it was really helpful after visualizing. that is what i was looking for. thanks alot. :)